# javascript regular expression to extract the code returned by content.html() in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a few javascript statements that I need to store in order to implement later in an undo/redo mechanism.

My statements consist of setting the HTML of the `content` div, and editing the global variable `i`. `$('#content')` can consist of many `divs` within it, each with their own inline style attributes. I was previously storing the multiple statements like this:

```
storedcontent = $('#content').html();
statements = "$('#content').html("+storedcontent+"); i = " +i+ "; ";
```

and then I would using `eval(str);`, when the undo button was pressed. 
An example of what might be stored in the `statements` variable is this:

```
content.html('<div id="left" class="margin-line" style="top: 15px; left: 15px; width:1px; height: 317px; border-right:1px dotted gray;"></div>     <div id="top" class="margin-line" style="top: 14px; left: 16px; height:1px; width: 569px; border-bottom:1px dotted gray; "></div>'); 
i = 3;
```

(Notice that after the .html() statement there's a variable assignment).

So what I was doing earlier was simply doing `eval(statements)`, in order to execute both the `.html()` and the `i=3` statements.

But I've realized `eval()` had problems. So while retaining the two (and there could more) javascript statements in the `statements` variable, I just want to extract whatever comes between the brackets in `$('#content').html()`.

So I want a regex to extract from the variable `statements`, only whatever's returned by `$('#content').html()`, i.e. whatever I had in `storedcontent`. That way, instead of using eval, I can directly do `$('#content').html(storedcontent);`

I know I could easily use substring but I would like to know how to do it using regular expressions.

I've tried to edit the question but I think it might still be confusing. To simplify, perhaps I'm just asking, how, using regex, can we capture the string between two different substrings, in this case `$('#content').html(` and `);`?

Comment: why don't you directly use the `storedcontent` variable?

Comment: Can you make the question a little more clear?

Comment: I've tried to clarify the question a bit more. I can't use `storedcontent` because it was only used in building the statements variable, which consists of multiple statements. I use this statements variable only later on when a user hits an `undo` button, and then I execute however many javascript commands `statements` consists of. But that wasn't working simply so I now want to extract the html specifically from it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why you're not using storedcontent but anyway.

What is inside the 'i' variable? If it's an integer, then the RegExp should be:

```
var storedcontent2 = statements.match(/#content\'\)\.html\((.*)(\);\s*i\s*=\s*\d+\s*;\s*)$/)[1];
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but got the error: `TypeError: statements.match(...) is null`. Yes `i` holds an integer, but I suppose by the time the statement `i=3` is stored inside the string `statements`, it's already become a string right? So that when I'm later trying to extract `$('#content').html()` from `statements`, probably everything is a string?